# Talend appends username with tablename

Tags: oracle, etl, talend

I am connecting my Oracle DB using tOracleOutput component. I used the "Oracle RAC" connection type. I specified URL, Username and Password. This connects perfectly.

But the problem is I am getting "table or view does not exists". I found the root cause that Talend appends the username to the table name. for example Select * from oracUser.my_table;

But I dont want the username to be included in the internal query that Talend generates.

Is there a way to specify Talend not to add username with table name for my ETL job?

Comment: You are connecting to the database, presumably, as `oracUser`.  If you want to query a table named `my_table` that is not in the `oracUser` schema, how are you making `oracUser` an identifier that resolves to the table you want?  Local synonyms?  Global synonyms?  By altering the `current_schema` with an `alter session`?

Comment: If the table is not in the schema (user) you're logged in as, what schema is it in? You'll need to supply that schema name if you want to get to the data; if you're logged in as `oracUser` but your table has been created in the `MYDATA` schema you'll need to give the fully-qualified name of the table, e.g. `MYDATA.MY_TABLE`. Best of luck.

Comment: My tables are created in different schema and only our DBA has access/privileges to it. But, we have a public synonym created for all the tables and we done require schema name with table name